# How to UPDATE using CASE to count if an ID is in multiple rows

Tags: sql-server, count, case

I have data below for example in a table let's call MainData:

```
ID        Name        RevenueDate        RevenueID        Account
100       James        2019-05-15         R-150           A100
100       James        2019-05-15         R-151           A100
100       James        2019-05-15         R-152           A100
```

My goal is to write an update statement that will update the "Account" column based on matching the ID and RevenueID back to a temp table that contains the ID and RevenueID along with the new "Account" values. But I would only want to do this for the rows where an ID value in the column "ID" has a count greater than 1  AND the "RevenueDate" is the same for all of the counts, AND the "RevenueID" column has to be different values.

My temp table looks something like this, let's just call it #acct:

```
ID        RevenueID         Account
100        R-150             A500
100        R-151             A600
100        R-152             A800
```

So ideally after the update based on referencing the temp table #acct, the new values for the "Account" column in the MainData table should now be A500, A600, A800 respectively.

Is it possible to go about in writing an UPDATE with a CASE expression inside to do this based on the criteria of where the rows where an ID value in the column "ID" has a count greater than 1 AND the "RevenueDate" is the same for all of the counts, AND the "RevenueID" column has to be different values?

Comment: How does the `#acct` comes about ? Is it created manually ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @MainData TABLE (
    ID INT, [Name] VARCHAR(10), RevenueDate DATE, RevenueID VARCHAR(10), Account VARCHAR(10)
);
INSERT INTO @MainData ( ID, [Name], RevenueDate, RevenueID, Account ) VALUES
    ( 100, 'James', '2019-05-15', 'R-150', 'A100' ),
    ( 100, 'James', '2019-05-15', 'R-151', 'A100' ),
    ( 100, 'James', '2019-05-15', 'R-152', 'A100' ),
    ( 100, 'James', '2019-06-15', 'R-153', 'A100' );

DECLARE @Acct TABLE ( ID INT, RevenueID VARCHAR(10), Account VARCHAR(10) );
INSERT INTO @Acct ( ID, RevenueID, Account ) VALUES
    ( 100, 'R-150', 'A500' ),
    ( 100, 'R-151', 'A600' ),
    ( 100, 'R-152', 'A800' ),
    ( 100, 'R-153', 'A900' );

-- Update Account from @Acct where ID + RevenueDate have a COUNT > 1.
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT
        ID, [Name], RevenueDate, RevenueID, Account, RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY ID, RevenueDate ) AS Rnk
    FROM @MainData
)
UPDATE CTE
SET
    Account = a.Account
FROM CTE 
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT COUNT ( * ) AS ct FROM CTE AS i WHERE i.Rnk = CTE.Rnk 
) AS x
INNER JOIN @Acct AS a
    ON CTE.ID = a.ID AND CTE.RevenueID = a.RevenueID
WHERE
    x.ct > 1;

-- Show updated resultset.
SELECT * FROM @MainData;
```

Updated resultset:

```
+-----+-------+-------------+-----------+---------+
| ID  | Name  | RevenueDate | RevenueID | Account |
+-----+-------+-------------+-----------+---------+
| 100 | James | 2019-05-15  | R-150     | A500    |
| 100 | James | 2019-05-15  | R-151     | A600    |
| 100 | James | 2019-05-15  | R-152     | A800    |
| 100 | James | 2019-06-15  | R-153     | A100    |
+-----+-------+-------------+-----------+---------+
```

Initial contents of @MainData:

```
+-----+-------+-------------+-----------+---------+
| ID  | Name  | RevenueDate | RevenueID | Account |
+-----+-------+-------------+-----------+---------+
| 100 | James | 2019-05-15  | R-150     | A100    |
| 100 | James | 2019-05-15  | R-151     | A100    |
| 100 | James | 2019-05-15  | R-152     | A100    |
| 100 | James | 2019-06-15  | R-153     | A100    |
+-----+-------+-------------+-----------+---------+
```

Initial contents of @Acct:

```
+-----+-----------+---------+
| ID  | RevenueID | Account |
+-----+-----------+---------+
| 100 | R-150     | A500    |
| 100 | R-151     | A600    |
| 100 | R-152     | A800    |
| 100 | R-153     | A900    |
+-----+-----------+---------+
```

Underlying resultset of CTE used for updating:

```
+-----+-------+-------------+-----------+---------+-----+----+
| ID  | Name  | RevenueDate | RevenueID | Account | Rnk | ct |
+-----+-------+-------------+-----------+---------+-----+----+
| 100 | James | 2019-05-15  | R-150     | A100    |   1 |  3 |
| 100 | James | 2019-05-15  | R-151     | A100    |   1 |  3 |
| 100 | James | 2019-05-15  | R-152     | A100    |   1 |  3 |
| 100 | James | 2019-06-15  | R-153     | A100    |   4 |  1 |
+-----+-------+-------------+-----------+---------+-----+----+
```

**UPDATE:**

If you want to exclude any duplicate ID/RevenueID/RevenueDate values from the UPDATE, you can try this:

```
DECLARE @MainData TABLE (
    ID INT, [Name] VARCHAR(10), RevenueDate DATE, RevenueID VARCHAR(10), Account VARCHAR(10)
);
INSERT INTO @MainData ( ID, [Name], RevenueDate, RevenueID, Account ) VALUES
    ( 100, 'James', '2019-05-15', 'R-150', 'A100' ),
    ( 100, 'James', '2019-05-15', 'R-151', 'A100' ),
    ( 100, 'James', '2019-05-15', 'R-152', 'A100' ),
    ( 100, 'James', '2019-05-15', 'R-152', 'A100' ),
    ( 100, 'James', '2019-06-15', 'R-153', 'A100' );

DECLARE @Acct TABLE ( ID INT, RevenueID VARCHAR(10), Account VARCHAR(10) );
INSERT INTO @Acct ( ID, RevenueID, Account ) VALUES
    ( 100, 'R-150', 'A500' ),
    ( 100, 'R-151', 'A600' ),
    ( 100, 'R-152', 'A800' ),
    ( 100, 'R-153', 'A900' );

-- Update Account from @Acct where ID + RevenueDate have a COUNT > 1.
WITH CTE AS (

    SELECT
        ID, [Name], RevenueDate, RevenueID, Account, RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY ID, RevenueDate ) AS Rnk
    FROM @MainData md WHERE NOT EXISTS (

        -- Exclude any ID/RevenueID/RevenueDate values that have duplicates.
        SELECT * FROM @MainData mdx 
        WHERE 
            mdx.ID = md.ID
            AND mdx.RevenueID = md.RevenueID
            AND mdx.RevenueDate = md.RevenueDate
        GROUP BY mdx.ID, mdx.RevenueID, mdx.RevenueDate
        HAVING COUNT ( * ) > 1

    )

)
UPDATE CTE
SET
    Account = a.Account
FROM CTE 
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT COUNT ( * ) AS ct FROM CTE AS i WHERE i.Rnk = CTE.Rnk 
) AS x
INNER JOIN @Acct AS a
    ON CTE.ID = a.ID AND CTE.RevenueID = a.RevenueID
WHERE
    x.ct > 1;

-- Show updated resultset.
SELECT * FROM @MainData;
```

Updated resultset (R-152 excluded due to ID/RevenueID/RevenueDate duplication):

```
+-----+-------+-------------+-----------+---------+
| ID  | Name  | RevenueDate | RevenueID | Account |
+-----+-------+-------------+-----------+---------+
| 100 | James | 2019-05-15  | R-150     | A500    |
| 100 | James | 2019-05-15  | R-151     | A600    |
| 100 | James | 2019-05-15  | R-152     | A100    |
| 100 | James | 2019-05-15  | R-152     | A100    |
| 100 | James | 2019-06-15  | R-153     | A100    |
+-----+-------+-------------+-----------+---------+
```

These were the starting rows of @MainData. Note the duplicate R-152.

```
+-----+-------+-------------+-----------+---------+
| ID  | Name  | RevenueDate | RevenueID | Account |
+-----+-------+-------------+-----------+---------+
| 100 | James | 2019-05-15  | R-150     | A100    |
| 100 | James | 2019-05-15  | R-151     | A100    |
| 100 | James | 2019-05-15  | R-152     | A100    |
| 100 | James | 2019-05-15  | R-152     | A100    |
| 100 | James | 2019-06-15  | R-153     | A100    |
+-----+-------+-------------+-----------+---------+
```

Comment: In this scenario it may not have any duplicate RevenueIDs, but in the case that I would need to add in the exclusion of duplicate RevenueIDs from the counts, where would that be added?

Comment: That depends. Are you stating that any records with duplicate RevenuIDs should be excluded? If not, how do you determine which record receives the update?

Comment: Yes any record that has the same ID, date, and also the same RevenueID should be excluded, so if the record has all 3 of these criteria, I would need to exclude them from the update

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much for your detailed answer! Definitely will note this so that I learn from it.

Comment: You're welcome, @jwalls91. Please note that I made a minor update to the exclusion in CTE. I added the additional criteria `mdx.ID = md.ID` as I missed that the first time.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a CASE statement. A simple join will allow you to copy the values from the temp table to the Main Table.

-- updated to use data & handle grouping criteria clarified in other comments.

Here's a re-runnable example.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Maindata') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Maindata
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#acct') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #acct

SELECT * INTO #Maindata FROM (VALUES
    ( 100, 'James', '2019-05-15', 'R-150', 'A100' ),
    ( 100, 'James', '2019-05-15', 'R-151', 'A100' ),
    ( 100, 'James', '2019-05-15', 'R-152', 'A100' ),
    ( 100, 'James', '2019-05-15', 'R-152', 'A100' ),
    ( 100, 'James', '2019-06-15', 'R-153', 'A100' )
) S(ID, Name, RevenueDate, RevenueID, Account)

SELECT * INTO #acct FROM (VALUES
    ( 100, 'R-150', 'A500' ),
    ( 100, 'R-151', 'A600' ),
    ( 100, 'R-152', 'A800' ),
    ( 100, 'R-153', 'A900' )
) S(ID, RevenueID, Account)

-- Main Table
SELECT * FROM #Maindata

-- Temp Table
SELECT * FROM #acct

UPDATE M SET
    Account = A.Account
FROM
    #Maindata M
    JOIN #acct A ON
        A.ID = M.ID AND
        A.RevenueID = M.RevenueID
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT ID, RevenueID, RevenueDate FROM #Maindata M GROUP BY ID, RevenueID, RevenueDate HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    ) S ON
        S.ID = M.ID AND
        S.RevenueID = M.RevenueID AND
        S.RevenueDate = M.RevenueDate
WHERE
    S.ID IS NULL
    
-- Updated Main Table
SELECT * FROM #Maindata
```